# What is the difference in meaning between "walk by someone" and "walk past someone"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference in meaning between *walk by someone* and *walk past someone*? For example:

> The other day, Sara **walked by** me and didn't even say hello, but then she did a double take and said she hadn't recognized me.
>
> The other day, Sara **walked past** me and didn't even say hello, but then she did a double take and said she hadn't recognized me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific context, they mean the same. "Walk by" seems to be favoured slightly more by American English speakers and "walk past" by British English speakers.

Note though that in British English, to "go by" somewhere can mean to go *via* that place, or even to visit that place. For example "I went by the shops today" in British English means that you visited the shops.

Answer (score 2):

They are synonymous (in US English).

But you might want to consider how the word choice will be perceived by the reader. **past** is a description of a specific kind of motion, in which Sara is physically close to you, and her body is moving relative to your body in space. **by** is more general and does not specifically describe motion.

So I recommend using **past** when you want to emphasize the fact that Sara is *walking* and that she is *passing you*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm confused. Could you clearify one point. You said that when someone walks past you, your body is relatively close to yours. But, doesn't "by" denote that?  What kind of specific motion are talking about in your answer?

Comment: In the specific sentence you quoted, they both have the same implication. But compare "I walked by the shop" and "I walked past the shop" - the latter is a specific physical description, the former is not.

Comment: Thank you, but could you clearify what you mean by specific physical descrption. I can't see how "I walked past the shop" is more specific than "I walked by the shop".